# Redirect all sub domain to another domain apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to redirect all sub domains of my webserver sites that start with mail to a https://anotherSub.domain.com

How can i do it?

```
Put this at the top of the yours default apache config file
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^SUBDOMAIN.* 
RewriteRule ^(.*) YOUR LINK (ex. http://www.google.it)
```

Comment: Put this at the top of the yours default apache config file
`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^SUBDOMAIN.* 
RewriteRule ^(.*) YOUR LINK (ex. http://www.google.it)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code matches any subdomain that starts with `mail` on `domain.com` and rewrites it to a `https://anothersub.domain.com`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail(.*?).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://anothersub.domain.com/$1 [L, 301]
```